# How can I list all branches or files locked in TFS without using Power Tool?

Tags: tfs

Actually all locked branches are visible to the user who has locked them with *red tick* but its not visible to other users until they try to check-ins. So is there any way to find out locked files or branches without using TFS Power tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), the **Status Sidekick** application pane provides the feature that "View lock icon indication in pending changes tree to easily identify locks".